# Can the company lock specific badges?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, badges

When I barely started using **Meta Stack Exchange**, I was surprised that I couldn't access a bronze medal. The "Altruist" badge requires ***75*** reputation, and the "Commentator" badge ***50!*** I even see silver and gold badges requiring reputation, too. 
 I am feature requesting locking specific badges.

## Why do I want you guys to lock them?

Because, it makes no sense! It makes no sense that you just see the badge and not put a lock icon over it, so you know that you cannot access it yet! So, I am feature requesting, please, lock the badges that require reputation.

Comment: [How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying) which says *Heavily consider not requesting a new feature if you're new*

Comment: The badge rules are described in *[What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397)*.

Answer (score 8):

You can always comment on your own questions and answers so you can get the commentator badge at any reputation level simply by doing that.

Answer (score 6):

> The "Altruist" badge requires 75 reputation, and the "Commentator" badge 50!

This is not true. When you have 100 reputation and post a bounty on somebody else's question, your reputation will be 50 but you'd still qualify for the Altruist badge. Similarly, downvotes can cause you to lose comment privileges, but that does not mean you can't get the badge anymore. They are not awarded instantly.